# Access SOAP request in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am working in IVR team. I write SOAP web services, write java client to access those web services and set data in the session variables of the CISCO API and IVR can then able to access that data. I am very good at this.

Currently, my manager plans to move from CISCO IVR to Amazon Connect. Amazon Connect has all infrastructure and IVR can be set up in 45 minutes. 
My task is to access existing legacy SOAP web services(which has access to our databases) in AWS Lambda and give that data to IVR.
I went through all the documentation, but not able to figure out where to start. Could some one give me guidance on where to start.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article about calling SOAP services from a Lambda function, with a walkthrough of the process: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/12/serverless-soap-legacy-api-integration-java-aws-lambda-aws-api-gateway/

It goes further than what you may need, adding API gateway on top of the Lambda function. You may not need that if you're just planning to call those Lambda functions from Connect.

There's also an article in Connect documentation on integrating with Lambda: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html